# Set Size Of Object To Perfectly Align 64x64 Image

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm making a really low poly character, he is literally made out of cubes with various size vectors. I want to be able to draw on him using a 64x64px image which is basically pixel art and I want the pixels to fit perfectly with the UV. I've tried everything, even making the image 100x100px and then making the size of the object rounded to one decimal so from 0.1 to 1. All I need is a formula that I can use to get the closest value for each axis (X, Y, Z) to which the pixels will be aligned in a 64x64px image where each limb is a separate cube with it's own texture and UV Map. For example in the X axis of my arm the size I gave it is 0.3 and for it to perfectly align the UV with the texture it must 0.325(example). Or if there is a simpler way do this please tell me. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Representation]

Comment: Is it necessary to "set the size of the object"? Or are you only interested in clean UV islands? There is an option in the UV/Image editor in the UV menu called *Snap to Pixels*. With this option activated, "moving" (G key, 0, Enter) the UV vertices will snap them to the closest pixel grid points. Making sure that e.g. the aspect ratio for the limbs or their relative size is correct then is another task.

Comment: It was that simple, thanks. Seems kind of stupid but I couldn't find the answer anywhere and I'm kind of bad at 3D graphics I'm literally only good at blending colors and picking color pallets. Edit my question if you think it's unclear and post the answer just in case someone runs into the same problem and I'll mark it as solved. Thanks again been trying to figure this out a long time now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's sufficient to align the UV islands to the pixel grid of the image, then you can snap selected vertices to the pixel grid with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > **Snap Selected to Pixels**.

Additionally, there's the option to snap the vertices with every transformation by activating **UVs > Snap to Pixels** in the menu of the UV/Image Edtior.

[image: snap to pixels]

If the proportions within your texture are important, you should make sure to align and scale all islands so that they approximately lie on the grid *before* you snap them to it. Otherwise your islands will be distorted:

[image: snapping gone wrong]